# Component Overlay via React Native

Tags: user-interface, overlay, react-native

I'm attempting to achieve the following (with the title component midway above the title image and component body):

[image: desired UI layout]

But it seems the best I can do so far is to utilize the Modal component to overlay. However, this is not optimal as the modal has a delayed exit when the user swipes back to the feed. Any ideas on how to implement this type of layout with views?

Here's my code:

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
    View, 
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    Text, 
    Modal,  
    ScrollView,
    AsyncStorage
} = React;

//additional libraries
var Parse = require('parse/react-native');
//var Reflux = require('reflux');

//dynamic component references
var Api = require('../../utils/api');

//libraries 


//dimensions
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var window = Dimensions.get('window');
var HTMLView = require('react-native-htmlview');
var ImageButton = require('../../common/imageButton');

module.exports = React.createClass({ 
    componentDidMount: function() {
    }, 
    componentWillMount: function() {
        Parse.User.currentAsync()
            .then((user) => { this.setState({user: user}); })
    },  
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            entry: null, 
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
                <View style={[styles.header, this.border('red')]}>
                    <Image source={{uri:'http://blameebro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/kdot-alright-video.png' }} style={[styles.entryImage]}>
                        <Modal
                          animated={false}
                          transparent={true}
                          visible={true}>
                             <View style={[styles.headerTopRow, this.border('yellow'), styles.overlay]}>
                                <Text style={styles.titleText}>These 3 Black Comedians Are Finally Being Honored For The Ways They Paved & The History They Made</Text>
                            </View>
                        </Modal>
                    </Image>
                </View>
                <View style={[styles.footer, this.border('blue')]}>
                    <View style={[styles.footerTopRow, this.border('red')]}>
                        <View style={styles.group}>
                            <ImageButton
                                style={[styles.btn]}
                                resizeMode={'contain'}
                                onPress={this.onPressSite}
                                source={require('../../img/globe-details.png')} />
                            <Text style={styles.sideText}>codeblackreport.com</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.group}>
                            <ImageButton
                                style={[styles.btn]}
                                resizeMode={'contain'}
                                onPress={this.onPressFave}
                                source={require('../../img/check-details.png')} />
                            <Text style={styles.sideText}>2.6k favorites</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <Image 
                        style={[styles.loginBar]}
                        resizeMode={'contain'}
                        source={require('../../img/login_bar_3x.png')} />
                    <View style={[styles.content, this.border('blue')]}>
                        <HTMLView
                            style={{backgroundColor:'color'}}
                            value={'<p>A <a href="http://www.benedelman.org/publications/airbnb-guest-discrimination-2015-12-09.pdf">working paper</a> (pdf) from Harvard Business School released Wednesday found “widespread discrimination” by hosts against people with black-sounding names seeking home rentals, <a href="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/12/12/business/discrimination-by-airbnb-hosts-is-widespread-report-says.html">reports the New York Times</a>.</p>'}
                            stylesheet={styles_two} />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }, 
    border: function(color) {
        return {
          //borderColor: color, 
          //borderWidth: 4,
        } 
     },
     onPressFave: function() {

     }, 
     onPressSite: function() {

     }, 

});

var styles_two = StyleSheet.create({
    p: {
        color:'white', 
        fontSize: 12, 
        fontWeight: '200', 
        fontFamily: 'arial', 
    }
}); 

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1, 
        alignItems: 'center', 
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent', 
    }, 
    footer: {
        flex: 2,
        backgroundColor: '#222222',  
        height: window.height/3.5,
        width: window.width, 
        alignItems: 'center', 
    }, 
    header: {
        flex: 1, 
    }, 
    entryImage: {
        height: window.height/3,
        width: window.width, 
    }, 
    loginBar: {
        width: (window.width/1.3)/1.8, 
        height: (70/553)*((window.width/1.3)/1.8),
        marginTop: -10,
    },
    barHolder: {
        backgroundColor: "#222222", 
    }, 
    content:  {
        flex: 5,
        marginLeft: window.width/40,
        marginRight: window.width/40,
        marginTop: window.height/40, 
    },  
    headerTopRow: {
        width: window.width/1.2, 
        backgroundColor: '#1C1C1A', 
        alignItems: 'flex-end', 
        alignSelf: 'center', 
        opacity: 0.6, 
        marginTop: (window.height/3)*(4/5), 
    }, 
    footerTopRow: {
        flex: 1, 
        flexDirection: "row", 
        justifyContent: 'space-around', 
        width: window.width, 
        height: window.height/15, 
        marginTop: (window.height/10), 
    }, 
    group: {
        flexDirection: "row", 
        justifyContent: 'space-between', 
        alignItems: 'center', 
    }, 
    btn: {
        width: window.width/20,
        height: window.width/20,
    }, 
    sideText: {
        color:'white', 
        fontSize: 12, 
        fontFamily: 'arial', 
        margin: 10, 
        alignSelf: 'center', 
    }, 
    titleText: {
        fontFamily: 'Bebas Neue', 
        fontSize: 20, 
        padding: 6, 
        color: 'white', 
        letterSpacing: 1,
        textAlign: 'center'
    }, 
});
```

And How it looks now:

[image]

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Sorry about that - just inlcuded the edit with my code - although it superficially looks like I have done what I am looking to do - the modal exits at a delayed speed with the user swipes back to the feed - leaving about 0.3sec after they've already swiped back.

Comment: Is the overlay static like the other components, or does it meet to transition like an overlay?

Comment: Is this a static component? If it is a static component, then a pragmatic solution would be to use absolute positioning and make the components overlay.

Comment: @NaderDabit yes the overlay should be static, and move when the user scrolls up to see content.

Comment: @SteliosVoskos I'm quite new to absolute positioning and flexbox - could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this what you're trying to do?:

[image]

```
var {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
} = React;

import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
var windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
var windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

var Main = React.createClass ({

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.container} >
            <Image
                style={styles.entry}
                source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
              />
            <View style={styles.title}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>These 3 Black Comedians Are Finally Being Honored For The Ways They Paved & The History They Made</Text>
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas a metus vel nibh scelerisque tempor. Sed quis condimentum sem. Fusce malesuada ipsum blandit, consectetur risus non, sodales nulla. Aenean rhoncus erat nec metus dictum vulputate. Proin diam lectus, scelerisque a porttitor ut, pellentesque at ipsum. Nunc ut odio magna. In condimentum, dolor sit amet mollis suscipit, erat quam ornare risus, nec vulputate libero augue vitae augue. Nam bibendum in ante in vestibulum. Etiam leo dolor, egestas sit amet nulla et, auctor volutpat metus. Sed vel mauris vitae tellus vestibulum ullamcorper. Aliquam hendrerit sit amet ipsum sagittis ultricies.

Proin consequat, mi in tincidunt rutrum, augue lacus vehicula magna, eget dapibus dui neque non velit. Proin semper enim est, vitae molestie metus fermentum at. Maecenas a convallis metus. Nam bibendum tempor nunc eu rhoncus. Ut rutrum est vitae leo accumsan viverra. Nullam ex justo, hendrerit in placerat at, convallis et orci. Morbi quis convallis sapien, quis tempor dui. Maecenas tristique augue quis viverra volutpat. Donec vel nisi at dolor blandit porttitor ut non urna.

Nulla facilisi. Sed vel gravida velit, elementum vehicula lacus. Praesent luctus eget neque eget vehicula. Vestibulum diam urna, sagittis at velit at, fermentum luctus arcu. Sed sapien arcu, pellentesque a lorem quis, varius porttitor mauris. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam rhoncus sollicitudin pretium. Aliquam eleifend turpis in posuere pellentesque. Vivamus viverra maximus lacus, sit amet cursus elit lobortis gravida. Quisque mollis velit quis dictum convallis. Vivamus non lectus auctor, blandit diam eu, lobortis odio. Nulla id pulvinar nulla.

Morbi et ex sagittis, pharetra dui ut, viverra augue. In commodo, libero nec pulvinar luctus, metus justo accumsan nisi, et congue dolor est a mauris. Mauris lacinia mi porta felis commodo, id finibus neque ullamcorper. Mauris ac ex at eros aliquam rutrum. Aenean venenatis quis neque non facilisis. Ut auctor, risus in laoreet bibendum, magna leo mollis turpis, a convallis mauris lorem sed nunc. Nulla et urna blandit, maximus lacus non, egestas sem. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

Integer in justo in erat euismod volutpat. Nam eleifend auctor ornare. Sed commodo felis sed diam mattis vulputate. Nam cursus placerat nunc. Aliquam sem nunc, fringilla sagittis lorem quis, pulvinar rhoncus erat. Integer venenatis, nibh sed vulputate facilisis, mi eros aliquam neque, ac consectetur leo augue id lorem. Mauris efficitur aliquet neque sed sagittis. Donec et sapien nisl.</Text>

        </ScrollView>

      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: "#444",
        flex: 1
    },
    text:{
        color: "white",
        margin: 16,
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    title:{
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)",
        marginHorizontal: 30,
        marginTop: -45,
    },
    entry: {
        height: windowHeight/3,
        width: windowWidth, 
    }


});
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea how to replicate an overlay over a picture with a low opacity without affecting the overlapping text? I've been going at the problem for some time now here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553174/text-overlay-image-with-darkened-opacity-react-native

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a negative margin on the title?

```
<View style={[styles.header, this.border('red')]}>
    <Image source={{uri:'http://blameebro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/kdot-alright-video.png' }} style={[styles.entryImage]}/>
     <View style={[styles.headerTopRow, this.border('yellow'), styles.overlay]}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>These 3 Black Comedians Are Finally Being Honored For The Ways They Paved & The History They Made</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

Then in styles:

```
headerTopRow: {
    marginTop: -50, 
},
```

Comment: yeah that only makes the view containing the text go up instead of down

Comment: You could place the title in the view below it and then move it up using negative margin

Comment: but then the view would still be below the next view starting the body content - both would need to overlap the image and the body content